# Python function for calculating constraint range?

Tags: python, optimization

I have a large number of individual constraints and I would like to have one final constraint which summarizes them in python.

For example constraints:

```
2 =< x <= 6
3 =< x <= 6
x <= 5
x >= 4
```

Return:

```
4 =< x <= 5
```

Comment: You're going to have to provide a more concrete example of the format that the "constraints" are in.  Why can't you just iterate through them and find the min of the maxes and the max of the mins and be done?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @AirSquid thanks for your reply. I was thinking about iterating but the min of the maxes and max of the mins did not come to mind. Thanks a lot! Simple solution!